# Ant Test Compile Crashes

Tags: testing, ant, junit, build, compilation

I am trying to compile a class named TestsVorgabe wich represents a testsuite including five other tests. It works fine with normal JUnit testing, but when i try to compile it with ant i get an

**error: cannot find symbol**

Project structure like this:

1. project/src => Classes
2. project/test => TestClasses

To make sure i really get the correct .jars and include them i have two ways delivering them to Ant. My Ant Buildfile looks like this:

```html
  <property name="src.dir" location="src"/>
  <property name="build.dir" location="build"/>
  <property name="dist.dir"  location="dist"/>
  <property name="docs.dir" location="docs"/>
  <property name="test.dir" location="test"/>
  <property name="buildtest.dir" location="buildtest"/>
 
  <path id="src.path">    
     <pathelement path="src/"/>
  </path>
 
  <path id="compile.path">
     <path refid="src.path"/>
     <fileset dir="lib/">
         <include name="**/*.jar"/>
     </fileset>
  </path>

  <path id="unit.test.path">
     <path refid="compile.path"/>
     <pathelement path="test/"/>
  </path>
 
  <!--Löscht die erstellten Verzeichnisse und Sourcen-->
  <target name="clean">
   <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
   <delete dir="${buildtest.dir}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}"/>
    <delete dir="${docs.dir}"/>
  </target>
   
  <!--Erzstellt die Verzeichnisstruktur-->
  <target name="init">
   <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
   <mkdir dir="${buildtest.dir}"/>
   <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}"/>
   <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}"/>
   <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}/dist2"/>
  </target>

  <!--Kompiliert die Programm-Klassen-->
  <target name="compile">
   <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
    <classpath refid="compile.path"/>
   </javac>
  </target>
 
  <target name="compileUnitTests" depends="compile">
     <javac srcdir="test/" destdir="${buildtest.dir}">
         <classpath refid="unit.test.path"/>
     </javac>
  </target>

 
  <target name="runUnitTests" depends="compile">
     <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no">
     <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"/>
         <classpath refid="unit.test.path"/>
      <formatter type="plain"/>
      <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${buildtest.dir}">
                  <fileset dir="${test.dir}">
                      <include name="**/TestsVorgabe.java"/>
                      <exclude name="**/AllTests.class"/>
                      <exclude name="**/*$*.class"/>
                  </fileset>
      </batchtest>
     </junit>
  </target>
```

I have tried many ways to inculde the .jars and many ways of compiling the tests, but nothing seemed to work so i ended up with this (do not work too).

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed error message? I think there should be more info, like which simbol is not defined  and where exactly?

Comment: add <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" /> under <junit> ..</junit>  to see what is missing.

Comment: `GameCrashTest.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]   StringBuffer wort = WordQuiz.platzhalterGen("wasd");
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable WordQuiz
    [javac]   location: class GameCrashTest`
That would be the exact error Message, returning 8 times. I added your code @Bhavin Panchani, but it is not reached because the compile process crashes and stops the building process.

Comment: The class GameCrashTest looks like this:
`public class GameCrashTest {

 @Test
 public void testePlatzhalter() {
  StringBuffer wort = WordQuiz.platzhalterGen("wasd");
  assertFalse(wort.length() == 5);
 }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compile your sources with javac into the `${build.dir}` but you doesn't add that to the classpath of the junit task, this is an example from the [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html):

```
<classpath>
    <pathelement location="${build.tests}"/>
    <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
  </classpath>
```

Or check [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/ant/ant-and-junit-task-example/)(in the example: `${web.classes.dir}`).

Try to add build.dir to the junit task classpath, I hope this helps!

Comment: perfectly fixes the compile issue =)